# Как использовать IP сервера в качестве прокси?

Tags: vps, прокси, vds

На моем VPS 2 выделенных IP. Можно ли их использовать в качестве прокси сервера? А то перепробовал более сотни IP и никакой не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Достаточно поставить на VPS любой прокси-сервер. Хотя бы [squid](http://www.debianhelp.org/node/1713).

Comment: его я только что и установил, но получаю ошибку `Access Denied.`

Comment: @emtecif а вы пройдите до конца по инструкции - там есть стадия настройки ACL - включая сеть, откуда к прокси разрешен доступ. По умолчанию там вроде бы только локалхост, вам нужно явно открыть доступ, и, заодно, включить запрос имени и пароля.